# What are blocklists and why are they considered unreliable?

Tags: burg

I'm new to Linux and was just wondering what blocklists are and why they are considered unreliable.

Example of my problem:

```
will@Will-PC:~$ sudo burg-install /dev/sda1
/usr/sbin/burg-setup: warn: Attempting to install GRUB to a partition instead of the MBR.  This is a BAD idea..
/usr/sbin/burg-setup: warn: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
/usr/sbin/burg-setup: error: if you really want blocklists, use --force
```

The problem is: `/dev/sda1` is my MBR.

Any description of blocklists or advice to my problem will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why this is unreliable is because burg is still a work in progress, and that's why this is not installed by default on Ubuntu.

And a blocklist is something specific to grub/grub2/burg ( at least in the terminology ).

This is used to read data that are not part of a file system, ie by reading directly on the disk. You can see some information on https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Block-list-syntax.html#Block-list-syntax

And no, the MBR is not on /dev/sda1, this is on the beginning of the disk ( ie on /dev/sda, the first block ), and sda1 is the first partition.

So you should really check if this is not /dev/sda that you should use. However, since the bootloader is critical, I would double check everything if I were you before touching.

Comment: And why are they unreliable?